# Who said, “The exegesis favors the Calvinist”?

Tags: exegesis, reformed-theology, reference-request, calvin

I’m trying to find an obscure quote from a particular theologian who in his commentary on a particular verse of Scripture wrote something along the lines of the following:

> “The exegesis favors the Calvinist, but the implications [of the Calvinist interpretation] would be too difficult to bear.”

I vaguely remember it being an Anglican minister, but that is all I have to go on.

Does anyone know the quote to which I am referring, who said it, and where I could find it?

Comment: Is there anything else that you were able to recall since you asked this question that could help in the search for an answer?

Comment: @AndriesStander Unfortunately not. I may have to sift through my saved articles and search history, at this point.